# Which Stack Exchange site would be appropriate for physical trading card games?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, area-51

There are these:

- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/
- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

For questions on physical/online trading card games like,

- https://magic.wizards.com/en
- http://tcg.pokemon.com/
- https://en.ws-tcg.com/
- https://www.yugioh-card.com/
- https://metazoogames.com/
- https://hearthstone.blizzard.com/
- https://www.playgwent.com/en

Which Stack Exchange site would be appropriate? Is there a try-out on the trading card topic on Area 51? https://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Board and Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com) - It's a fairly well-established site and includes collectable card games.